# Custom Controller Factory not finding exports

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda, mef, controller-factory

The controllerName it is looking for is the correct name, and I know that the container has that export in it with the matching name. For some reason it doesn't find it. I am trying to import from dll's that I have put in a specified folder in the project. It will always try to return the default controller, but can't find the dll controller because it isn't in the main project directory. I know that the controllerFactory finds the DLL, but isn't reading it in properly.

Here is my CreateController Function:

```
Public Function CreateController(requestContext As System.Web.Routing.RequestContext, 
        controllerName As String) As System.Web.Mvc.IController Implements 
        System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory.CreateController





    Dim controller As IController = Nothing

    If controllerName IsNot Nothing Then



        Dim controllerClassName As String = controllerName & "Controller"




       Dim controllers As IEnumerable(Of Lazy(Of IController)) = Me.container.GetExports(Of IController)()

        Dim controllerExport As Lazy(Of IController) = controllers _
                                             .Where(Function(c) c.Value.GetType.Name = controllerName) _
                                             .FirstOrDefault()



        If export IsNot Nothing Then
            controller = export.Value
        End If

    End If

    If controller Is Nothing Then
        Return Me.defaultControllerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName)
    End If

    Return controller

End Function
```

**If you need anything clarified, please let me know! Thanks!**

EDIT: Error Message on the Return Me.defaultControllerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName) is HttpException was unhandled by user code. The controller path 'CUContractNumberPlugin/ChangeCUNumber' was not found or does not implement IController.

Here is the controller it is talking about.

```
<Export(GetType(IController)), ExportMetadata("Name", "CUContractNumberPlugin")> _
Public Class CUContractNumberPluginController
    Inherits Controller

    <Import(GetType(IHost))>
    Private m_hostApp As IHost


    Public Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function

    Function ChangeCUNumber(strCUNumber As String) As ActionResult
        m_hostApp.CUNumber = strCUNumber
        Return View("Index", m_hostApp)
    End Function

End Class
```

This is getting called when I am loading a partial view into my main view. The partial view is this:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeCUNumber", "CUContractNumberPlungin"))

    @Html.TextBox("strCUNumber")

End Using
```

Comment: could you post the error message

Comment: @Gilles I just added the error I am getting to the main post